# Is there a way to delete specific field in array?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to to add this button with function `deleteData` to delete a specific row on the screen for the `UI`. So if I have 3 emails listed, it would render 3 on screen. But if I were to click the `delete button` for any of them on their specified row, it would `delete` that whole row from the `array/UI`. I am currently stuck and not able to figure it out and am asking what a possible solution would look like.

**HTML:**

```
<template>
     <template for:each={emails} for:item='email'>
          <div key={email.index}>
               <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                         <lightning-input label="Email" title="Email" data-index={index} value={email.emails}></lightning-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                         <lightning-button type="button" variant="base" label="Delete" icon-name="utility:delete" onclick={deleteData}</lightning-button>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
     </template>
     <lightning-button type="button" variant="base" label="Add Email" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={clickedAddEmail}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
userEmails= [{index:0,eamils:''}]

clickedAddEmail(){
     this.userEmails=[...this.userEmails, {index:this.userEmails.length+1,emails:''}];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to do this in JS, but one of the easiest is to just [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it out:

```
deleteData(event) {
  const index = this.userEmails.findIndex(user => user.index === event.target.dataset.index)
  // at start index, delete 1 element
  this.userEmails.splice(index, 1)
  // Triggers render cycle
  this.userEmails = [...this.userEmails]
}
```

Make sure you add the property to your button, too:

```
<lightning-button data-index={email.index} type="button" variant="base" label="Delete" icon-name="utility:delete" onclick={deleteData}</lightning-button>
```